# How to download a bulk of images from a list with their url?

Tags: download, download-manager

I would like to download a list of png images. I have the url in a table (excel). How could I do this?

Comment: What did you try? You even tagged it "Download-Manager" did you try to use one?

Comment: I'm looking for one. Do you know any how can name the downloaded file based on another cell?

Comment: You could use a `for` loop with `wget` to download all images from a plain text file/list. If it needs to be a excel table, there may be a way to do it via VBA.

Comment: @jnL Definitely possible with VBA, however OP has not tried anything yet

Comment: `wget -i file-with-urls.txt` (i.e. notepad text that is)

Comment: @Hannu Thanks. Do you know how I can modify the name of the downloaded file? Because I have a list with URLs and foreach url a name, how I would like to name the file.

Comment: Have a look on the text displayed by `man wget` - or; google it if you don't have man-pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tab Save](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-save/lkngoeaeclaebmpkgapchgjdbaekacki). It's a chrome extension. You can know more about it [here](https://github.com/lmmx/tabsave/).
Also, if you want to know other alternatives, refer this [SuperUser Question](https://superuser.com/questions/274276/what-program-can-i-use-to-bulk-download-this-list-of-links).